How to get the values ​of Draw plugin objects?
I created an algorithm in Python that displays a web page with a map using the folium library and several markers based on the coordinates I entered into a spreadsheet. I inserted the Draw Plugin to draw objects, specifically a circle by clicking on the map and scaling the desired radius.
Is it possible to obtain the coordinate values ​​of the circle and what is its radius? I intend to use this information to calculate how many markers are within this radius.
I searched the folium library documentation and several websites, but I didn't find anything that helped me.

How did you draw the circle in the first place? Didn't have to give a center and radius to draw it?

I select the option to draw the circle in the drawing bar, click on the map and drag the mouse cursor to the desired radius. While I'm drawing the circle, the tool displays the radius in the corner.
